# Getting element height and insert it in a style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
function toggle_div(id) {

    var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
    var togglerBut = document.getElementById("menuToggler");
    var siteMenuHeight = document.getElementById('site-menu').offsetHeight;

   if(divelement.style.transform == 'translateY(0px)')
        divelement.style.transform = 'translateY(250px)';
   else
        divelement.style.transform = 'translateY(0px)';
}
```

which i use for reviling top "mega menu" style.

**Now i need to replace the 250px value in this line:**

```
divelement.style.transform = 'translateY(250px)';
```

To be what ever the "site-menu" `div` height is.

I get the `height` of the "site-menu" `div` into a `var` with this line:

```
var siteMenuHeight = document.getElementById('site-menu').offsetHeight;
```

**But i don't know how to insert it into to the style.transform action... How Do I Do This?**

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Do I Do This?

String concatenation:

```
divelement.style.transform = 'translateY(' + siteMenuHeight + 'px)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate it like this:

```
divelement.style.transform = 'translateY(' + siteMenuHeight + 'px)';
```